# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I wrote codes about fragment according to the [Google official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)
    and both of them are almost the same,but why I still got error that couldn't find the `TextView`.
    It consists of four java classes, and three layout files.I may want to work on the landscape,the tricky part is in the landscape,for the portrait works find.Therefore,I would only present the landscape code for well readability.

**activity_main.xml(land)**

As the demo does,my layout-landscape remains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
        class="com.example.jimjay.bookapp.List_fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/content_fragment"
        class="com.example.jimjay.bookapp.ContenFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**content_view.xml**

This for display text

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/container_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements List_fragment.OnListSelectedListener{

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            if (findViewById(R.id.container) != null) {

                if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                    return;
                }

                List_fragment firstFragment = new List_fragment();
                firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, firstFragment).commit();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChapterSelected(int position) {

            ContenFragment contenFragment=(ContenFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_fragment);
            if (contenFragment != null){
                contenFragment.updateContent(position);
            }else {

                ContenFragment newFragment = new ContenFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(ContenFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
                newFragment.setArguments(args);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                transaction.commit();
            }

        }
    }
```

**List_fragment.java**

```
public class List_fragment extends ListFragment {

        OnListSelectedListener mCallBack;

        interface OnListSelectedListener{
            void onChapterSelected(int position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            int layout=android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1;

            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),layout,new Book_content().chapters));

        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.list_fragment) != null){
                getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);

            try {
                mCallBack=(OnListSelectedListener) context;
            }catch (ClassCastException e){
                throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()+" must implement OnListSelectedListener");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            mCallBack.onChapterSelected(position);

            getListView().setItemChecked(position,true);
        }
    }
```

**ContenFragment.java**

```
public class ContenFragment extends Fragment {

final static String ARG_POSITION="position";
int mCurrentPosition=-1;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        mCurrentPosition=savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
    }

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_view,container,false);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Bundle args=getArguments();
    if (args!= null){
        updateContent(args.getInt(ARG_POSITION));
    }else if (mCurrentPosition != -1){
        updateContent(mCurrentPosition);
    }
}

public void updateContent(int position) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.container_content);
    if (textView != null) {
        textView.setText((new Book_content().contents_string[position]));
    }else {
        Log.e("LOG", "The textView is null");
    }
    mCurrentPosition = position;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putInt(ARG_POSITION,mCurrentPosition);
}
```

}

And the last Java file is `Book_content.class`, which just contain strings.
  So it worked in portrait, but not in landscape, I can't figure it out, and the problem I found is the `TextView` in `ContenFragment.class` raises the exception, which is null. but I did have a `TextView` in the `content_view`. Why is that? HELP

Answer (score 0):

Trying to figure it out myself,now I do.
It was odd that it still encountered the EXCEPTION,even if I just pasted the official sample codes in my classes directly.SO I have to turn to other instantiations.Changing the fragment in the right side into a fragmentLayout,let it be the same as the portrait layout.

> activity_main.xml(land)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
        class="com.example.jimjay.bookapp.List_fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"></FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

So just use the FragmentTransaction to add the contentFragment.